# Парсинг HTML (HtmlAgilityPack). Как получить картинку между текстом?

Tags: c#, html, парсер, htmlagilitypack

Пример HTML

```
<p class="left_margin"> 5)  
<img src="https://sait.ru/formula/svg/8b/8b847cfae498e96e3fa08a56cb42b838.svg" class="tex" style="vertical-align:0pt" />
    blablabla
</p>
```

Как после парсинга с помощью HtmlAgilityPack получить нечто подобное:

> 5) 
>   https://sait.ru/formula/svg/8b/8b847cfae498e96e3fa08a56cb42b838.svg 
>   blablabla

Т.е. последовательно получить текст, ссылку на картинку, текст последовательно.

Comment: ссылка на картинку будет хранится в виде текста(base64) среди прочего текста.

Comment: да, именно в виде текста и хочу, но не могу реализовать. Либо только текст, либо вместе с ссылкой, но в виде HTML кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала неправильно понял задание. Задача не такая тривиальная как мне показалось на первый взгляд.

В даном случае тебе нужно вытянуть InnerHTML родительской ноды, а потом уже убрать лишние тэги через регуларное выражение. Напрямую при помощи HTMLAgrillityPack-а ты такого результата вряд ли добьешся.

Хотя, можешь посмотреть в сторону `.NextSibling` -- может что-то придумаешь. Я просто давно пользовался библиотекой. Сходу могу и ошибится..

---

Я тут так подумал, а ты можешь вытягнуть сначала значение атрибута src, а потом заменить ноду с картинкой на текст с даного src. Попробуй реализовать, думаю что получится.

А потом вытягнуть .InnerText.

Comment: Разве там нету CSS селекторов? Тупо берем все тэги img. Далее берем значения из атрибутов и все. По идее, такая возможность есть в AngleSharp=> любой уважающий себя парсер должен иметь это.

Comment: @iluxa1810 я сначала тоже так задание понял) Здесь не линку из атрибута нужно достать, а текст ДО имеджа, атрибут имеджа, и текст после имеджа

Comment: Именно, вся соль в том, чтобы оставить атрибут src тега img именно в том месте, где он находится, а не просто отдельно получить текст и ссылку на картинку

Comment: @Alex я тут один костыль придумал, опробуй

Comment: Решение не изящное, но на первый взгляд работоспособно.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, закроем тег: заменим `<p>` на `</p>`.

В показанном html внутри тега `p` содержатся три узла: текстовый, `img`, текстовый.
Тег `img`, в свою очередь, сам содержит несколько атрибутов и текстовый узел.

Соответственно, теперь, вооружившись этими знаниями, мы можем получить текстовые узлы и значение атрибута вложенного узла.

```
var html = @"
<p class='left_margin'> 5)  
<img src='https://sait.ru/formula/svg/8b/8b847cfae498e96e3fa08a56cb42b838.svg' class='tex' style='vertical-align:0pt' />
    blablabla
</p>
";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var p = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p");

var textNodes = p.SelectNodes("text()")
    .Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim())
    .ToList();

var src = p.SelectSingleNode("img").Attributes["src"].Value;

Console.WriteLine(textNodes[0]); // 5)
Console.WriteLine(textNodes[1]); // blablabla
Console.WriteLine(src); // https://sait.ru/formula/svg/8b/8b847cfae498e96e3fa08a56cb42b838.svg
```

Вместо xpath, можно отфильтровать текстовые узлы с помощью linq:

```
var textNodes = p.ChildNodes
    .Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
    .Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim())
    .ToList();
```

Если нужно получить значения именно в том порядке, как они расположены, то:

```
var nodes = p.ChildNodes
    .Select(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text ? n.InnerText.Trim() : n.Attributes["src"].Value);
```

Ну и соединить их:

```
string result = string.Join(" ", nodes);
```

---

Или вопрос в том и заключался, что тег `p` не закрыт и парсер даёт сбой на его получении?

Comment: HTML представлен как есть, т.е. внутри <p> текст потом <img> потом текст и только после этого тег <p> закрывается.

Comment: У вас тег `p` **не** закрывается. Там идёт начало следующего тега. В этом и проблема?

Comment: Закрывается, опечатка :(

Comment: только это ж не универсально... А если попадется с другой структурой нода?

Comment: @Andrew - в конце универсальный пример: извлекаются текстовые узлы и атрибуты src, количество и порядок которых не важен.